# How can I tell if a jar file is being compiled into an apk?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, jar

In our Unity project we have a lot of jar files in **Assets/Plugins/Android**. I understand when Unity compiles for Android, any `.jar` or `.aar` files in that directory will make it into the compiled apk.

However, our app's Unity project has many folders next to the Assets folder, and in one of those is a hand full of jar files, such as `android-support-V4.jar` and `google-play-services.jar`. These are not in **Assets/Plugins/Android**, but some of the .jars in that directory depend on what's in the directory outside the Assets folder.

How can I tell if these `.jars` outside the Assets folder are making it into the compiled apk? I know it's a broad question, and part of it is idiosyncratic to how my company's project is set up, but basically I'm wondering if there are common or known ways to get `.jars` outside of the Assets folder into the apk Unity makes.

Comment: It is a nightmare.  Good luck  :/

Answer (score 2):

You can use a tool such as [Classyshark](https://github.com/google/android-classyshark) to analyze the contents of your apk. Classyshark is developed by Google for these kinds of inspections. You can see what packages and what classes are in your apk, no matter how these were packaged.

Comment: Cool, that'll at least tell me if those .jars outside the Assets folder are getting included or not. That's still an ambiguous point for me.